# How to run libvirt ubuntu headless mode?

Tags: virtual-machine, kvm, libvirt

I have created a simple vm ubuntu1604server using virt-manager on ubuntu1604desktop native. I can sucessfully run the vm with a window using the virt-manager gui, but I wish to run this vm in headless mode instead.

Is this possible and how is it achieved?

p.s. I've received a few downvotes, if there is ambiguity in the question then please can you point this out?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was misuing virsh list.

The following works for me:

```
virsh list --all
virsh start <name>
```